# pandas interpolate is not returning the expected results

Tags: python, pandas, interpolation

i have data points from a large CSV file which looks like:

```
MMSI,BaseDateTime,LAT,LON,SOG,COG

11,0,27.29237,-90.96787,0.1,195.7
11,360,27.29237,-90.96793,0.1,188.0
111, 0,27.3538,-94.6253,0.1,35.3
111,180,27.35376,-94.62543,0.1,225.5
```

The basedatetime is a measure of seconds from the first entry to the second entry.

My problem is, that i want to interpolate this data, so that instead of having these uneven entries in the basedate time, i want to have an entry for every 30 seconds instead, up to the final point.

To do this, i have created this code:

```
def interpolater(df: np.ndarray):
    # Create a Pandas DataFrame from the NumPy array
    df = pd.DataFrame(df, columns=['MMSI', 'BaseDateTime', 'LAT', 'LON', 'SOG', 'COG'])

    df = df.groupby(['MMSI'])
    interpolated_dfs = []

    for name, group in df:
        # Set 'BaseDateTime' as the index for each group
        group.set_index('BaseDateTime', inplace=True)
        group.index = pd.to_timedelta(group.index, unit='s')
        group = group.astype({'LAT': 'float32', 'LON': 'float32', 'SOG': 'float32', 'COG': 'float32'})
        group = group.infer_objects(copy=False)
        # Resample the data with a 30 integer intervals and interpolate linearly
        resampled_group = group.resample('30S').interpolate(method='linear')

        # Reset the index
        resampled_group.reset_index(inplace=True)

        # Convert the time-based index back to its original format (e.g., seconds)
        resampled_group['BaseDateTime'] = resampled_group['BaseDateTime'].dt.total_seconds()

        # Append the resampled group to the list of interpolated DataFrames
        interpolated_dfs.append(resampled_group)

    # Concatenate the list of DataFrames back into a single DataFrame
    interpolated_df = pd.concat(interpolated_dfs)

    # Convert the result to a NumPy array
    interpolated_data = interpolated_df.to_numpy()

    return interpolated_data
```

This code transforms the data as expected in the time dimension like so:

```
MMSI,BaseDateTime,Latitude,Longitude,SOG,COG
11,0.0,27.29237,-90.96787,0.1,195.7
11,30.0,27.29237,-90.96787,0.1,195.7
11,60.0,27.29237,-90.96787,0.1,195.7
11,90.0,27.29237,-90.96787,0.1,195.7
11,120.0,27.29237,-90.96787,0.1,195.7
11,150.0,27.29237,-90.96787,0.1,195.7
11,180.0,27.29237,-90.96787,0.1,195.7
11,210.0,27.29237,-90.96787,0.1,195.7
11,240.0,27.29237,-90.96787,0.1,195.7
11,270.0,27.29237,-90.96787,0.1,195.7
11,300.0,27.29237,-90.96787,0.1,195.7
11,330.0,27.29237,-90.96787,0.1,195.7
11,360.0,27.29237,-90.96787,0.1,195.7
111,0.0,27.3538,-94.6253,0.1,35.3
111,30.0,27.3538,-94.6253,0.1,35.3
111,60.0,27.3538,-94.6253,0.1,35.3
111,90.0,27.3538,-94.6253,0.1,35.3
111,120.0,27.3538,-94.6253,0.1,35.3
111,150.0,27.3538,-94.6253,0.1,35.3
111,180.0,27.3538,-94.6253,0.1,35.3
```

My problem is that the latitude, longtitude, sog, and cog dont have any sensible changes to them, and im not quite sure how to fix this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to tell `resample` how to resample. Try adding `mean()` for example:

`resampled_group = group.resample('30S').mean().interpolate(method='linear')`

See [the resampling docs](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/timeseries.html#resampling)